# Getting DLL error when running tensorflow/keras program on python gpu 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am trying to run my simple AI program but I keep getting this DLL error:

```
    ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. 
You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: 
https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

I went ahead and downloaded that support file and restarted my computer but that didn't work. I also found the specified dll file in my system 32 and made sure it was in my PATH environment for both system and user. Still doesn't work. I am using python3.8 with gpu enabled. Am
I missing something? Is this a version issue because it has never happened on my previous projects.

Here are my libraries:

```
_tflow_select   2.3.0   
absl-py 0.12.0  
aggdraw 1.3.12  
aiofiles    0.7.0   
aiohttp 3.7.4   
alembic 1.6.4   
argon2-cffi 20.1.0  
astor   0.8.1   
asttokens   2.0.5   
astunparse  1.6.3   
async-timeout   3.0.1   
async_generator 1.10    
attrs   20.3.0  
autokeras   1.0.16  
backcall    0.2.0   
beautifulsoup4  4.9.3   
blas    1.0 
bleach  3.3.0   
blinker 1.4 
brotlipy    0.7.0   
ca-certificates 2021.7.5    
cachetools  4.2.2   
certifi 2021.5.30   
cffi    1.14.5  
chardet 4.0.0   
click   7.1.2   
cliff   3.8.0   
cmaes   0.8.2   
cmd2    2.1.2   
colorama    0.4.4   
colorlog    5.0.1   
coverage    5.5 
cryptography    3.4.7   
cycler  0.10.0  
cython  0.29.23 
decorator   5.0.9   
defusedxml  0.7.1   
docopt  0.6.2   
entrypoints 0.3 
executing   0.6.0   
fastapi 0.65.1  
flaml   0.6.9   
flatbuffers 1.12    
freetype    2.10.4  
gast    0.4.0   
gin-config  0.4.0   
google-auth 1.30.0  
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.4   
google-pasta    0.2.0   
greenlet    1.1.0   
grpcio  1.34.1  
h11 0.12.0  
h5py    3.1.0   
hdf5    1.10.5  
icc_rt  2019.0.0    
icecream    2.1.0   
icu 58.2    
idna    2.10    
importlib-metadata  3.10.0  
importlib_metadata  3.10.0  
intel-openmp    2021.2.0    
ipykernel   5.3.4   
ipython 7.25.0  
ipython_genutils    0.2.0   
ipywidgets  7.6.3   
jedi    0.18.0  
jinja2  3.0.1   
joblib  1.0.1   
jpeg    9b  
jsonschema  3.2.0   
jupyter_client  6.1.12  
jupyter_core    4.7.1   
jupyterlab_pygments 0.1.2   
jupyterlab_widgets  1.0.0   
keras   2.7.0   
keras-applications  1.0.8   
keras-nightly   2.5.0.dev2021032900 
keras-preprocessing 1.1.2   
keras-tuner 1.0.4   
kiwisolver  1.3.1   
kt-legacy   1.0.4   
libclang    12.0.0  
libpng  1.6.37  
libprotobuf 3.14.0  
libsodium   1.0.18  
libtiff 4.1.0   
lightgbm    3.3.1   
llvmlite    0.37.0  
lxml    4.6.3   
lz4-c   1.9.3   
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran   5.3.0   
m2w64-gcc-libs  5.3.0   
m2w64-gcc-libs-core 5.3.0   
m2w64-gmp   6.1.0   
m2w64-libwinpthread-git 5.0.0.4634.697f757  
mako    1.1.4   
markdown    3.3.4   
markupsafe  2.0.1   
matplotlib  3.3.4   
matplotlib-base 3.3.4   
matplotlib-inline   0.1.2   
mistune 0.8.4   
mkl 2021.2.0    
mkl-service 2.3.0   
mkl_fft 1.3.0   
mkl_random  1.2.1   
msys2-conda-epoch   20160418    
multidict   5.1.0   
nbclient    0.5.3   
nbconvert   6.1.0   
nbformat    5.1.3   
nest-asyncio    1.5.1   
notebook    6.4.0   
numba   0.54.0  
numexpr 2.7.3   
numpy   1.19.5  
oauthlib    3.1.0   
olefile 0.46    
opencv-contrib-python   4.5.3.56    
opencv-python   4.5.3.56    
openssl 1.1.1k  
opt-einsum  3.3.0   
opt_einsum  3.1.0   
optuna  2.8.0   
orca    1.6 
packaging   20.9    
pandas  1.2.4   
pandocfilters   1.4.3   
parso   0.8.2   
pbr 5.6.0   
pickleshare 0.7.5   
pillow  8.2.0   
pip 21.3.1  
pipreqs 0.4.10  
plotly  4.14.3  
plotly-orca 1.3.1   
prettytable 2.1.0   
prometheus_client   0.11.0  
prompt-toolkit  3.0.17  
protobuf    3.16.0  
psutil  5.8.0   
pyasn1  0.4.8   
pyasn1-modules  0.2.8   
pycparser   2.20    
pydantic    1.8.1   
pydot   1.4.2   
pygments    2.9.0   
pyjwt   2.1.0   
pyopenssl   20.0.1  
pyparsing   2.4.7   
pyperclip   1.8.2   
pyqt    5.9.2   
pyreadline  2.1 
pyreadline3 3.3 
pyrsistent  0.17.3  
pysocks 1.7.1   
python  3.8.0   
python-dateutil 2.8.1   
python-dotenv   0.17.1  
python-editor   1.0.4   
python-multipart    0.0.5   
python_abi  3.8 
pytz    2021.1  
pywin32 227 
pywinpty    0.5.7   
pyyaml  5.4.1   
pyzmq   20.0.0  
qt  5.9.7   
requests    2.25.1  
requests-oauthlib   1.3.0   
retrying    1.3.3   
rsa 4.7.2   
scikit-learn    0.24.2  
scipy   1.6.2   
seaborn 0.11.1  
send2trash  1.5.0   
setuptools  52.0.0  
sip 4.19.13 
six 1.15.0  
soupsieve   2.2.1   
sqlalchemy  1.4.22  
sqlite  3.35.4  
starlette   0.14.2  
stevedore   3.3.0   
tables  3.6.1   
tensorboard 2.7.0   
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1   
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0   
tensorflow  2.5.0   
tensorflow-addons   0.13.0  
tensorflow-base 2.3.0   
tensorflow-estimator    2.5.0   
tensorflow-gpu  2.4.1   
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.21.0  
termcolor   1.1.0   
terminado   0.9.4   
testpath    0.5.0   
threadpoolctl   2.1.0   
tk  8.6.10  
toolz   0.11.1  
tornado 6.1 
tqdm    4.61.2  
traitlets   5.0.5   
typeguard   2.12.1  
typing-extensions   3.7.4.3 
typing_extensions   3.7.4.3 
urllib3 1.26.4  
uvicorn 0.13.4  
vc  14.2    
visualkeras 0.0.2   
vs2015_runtime  14.27.29016 
watchgod    0.6 
wcwidth 0.2.5   
webencodings    0.5.1   
websockets  8.1 
werkzeug    1.0.1   
wheel   0.36.2  
widgetsnbextension  3.5.1   
win_inet_pton   1.1.0   
wincertstore    0.2 
winpty  0.4.3   
wrapt   1.12.1  
xgboost 1.3.3   
xz  5.2.5   
yaml    0.2.5   
yarg    0.1.9   
yarl    1.6.3   
zeromq  4.3.3   
zipp    3.4.1   
zlib    1.2.11  
zstd    1.4.9
```

Comment: Just to make sure: what folder is `msvcp140_1.dll` in? Is that folder in the `PATH` environment variable (system, preferrably), separated by semicolons (`;`)?

Comment: It is in my C:\Windows\System32 and yes, that directory is in my Path environment variable.

Comment: What are you using to run the program?

Answer (score 2):

First, check to see if `msvcp140.dll` (*not `msvcp140_1.dll`*) is installed.

Download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

Restart your computer and see if it works.

If that doesn't work try copying `msvcp140_1.dll` into: `C:\Users\PCName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`

If nothing still works, it could be a version issue.

As far as I know, Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.
Run this:

```
pip install tensorflow ==2.2.0
```

Look here for system requirements: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements

**Tensorflow will work only on `Windows 7 or later (64-bit)` (According to the above link)**

Package location: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.7.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

**If you are using 32-bit python,
replace your 32-bit python with a 64-bit version. Tensorflow does not support 32-bit architecture.**

Comment: I will go ahead and do that. Can you clarify on the installation of the Python with the latest TF version? Is there a specific version I should be looking for with python3.8?

Comment: Yes, try to look for version 2.2. (Look at my updated answer)

Comment: Tried all of what was suggested. Still no dice. I have 64-bit python with 2.2 tf and downloaded all proper downloads like the visual c++ and added both dll files to the python38 file as well as add that directory to environment variables

Comment: Tough, did you make sure that you check all the tensorflow system requirements?

Comment: Yeah I am going to try and totally nuke my python environments, Conda, and packages and try from scratch. Will update soon